# Are Kinetic Energy and Thermal energy easily equatable?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, kinematics, energy-conservation

This is all hypothetical, and I'm literally making it up on the fly, so if the situation seems bizare, that's why.

If I know that it takes 20 kJ of energy to raise an object's temperature by 1 degree celcius, and I planned on shooting a bb gun at an object. Let's pretend the Kinetic Energy of one bb is 0.1 J, Can I reasonable say that it would take (20 kJ / 0.0001 kJ) or 200,000 bbs hitting the object to raise the object's temperature by 1 degree C?

Can I equate Thermal and Kinetic energy in that way?

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't easily equate thermal and kinetic energy in this way without qualifiers such as the following.

(1) We must keep the object completely insulated (and soundproof) to avoid heat loss to the environment.

(2) The BBs must come to a stop at/in the object (as opposed to bouncing off) to completely convert their kinetic energy to heat.

(3) We then have to raise the temperature of the BBs as well.

(4) Some of the energy would go into producing vast numbers of dislocations (lattice defects) in the materials as they permanently deform. This energy is not available for heating.

Other qualifiers may exist as well.